# YouTube player below "minimum" size

Tags: javascript, css, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

The YouTube API docs define the minimum size of an embedded player t to be 200px by 200px ([link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Requirements)).

> To allow room for critical player functionality, players must be at least 200px by 200px.

My testing has lead me to the conclusion that this is true. If I try to play a video in a player which is smaller than the minimum size, I get an error message which says "Video player  is too small." and the video will not play.

However, smaller players are possible. [SwitchCam](http://make.switchcam.com/), for example, uses them on pages [like this one](http://switchcam.com/event/josh-rio-san-francisco-skate-park-4/?largeembed&width=950&height=620&client=Testing&v=1-1&project_token=XdG8d42EvWjrYpVa&autoplay=true&seek-back=1).

[image: SwitchCam small players]

I've tried reducing the player size by setting it's height and width attributes, by using it's style attribute and by wrapping it in a containing element which has it's height and width set. None of these options appear to work.

What else can I try to reduce the size of the player?

**EDIT**

It appears that some videos will play in really small players but others will not. If you're going to test a potential solution, please use this video ID: `-rMTExNTx2s`

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/html5 <-- curious, are you taking part in the trial?

Comment: I think that trial just gets you the HTML5 player when you're on the YouTube site. I'm talking about using the YouTube player API, which is a different thing all together.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's true. I started creating unit tests for a jQuery plugin that I authored (tubeplayer: https://github.com/nirvanatikku/jQuery-TubePlayer-Plugin) and I noticed that the minimum player size error (onErrorNotEmbeddable) doesn't actually get thrown if I've enabled the trial. Basically, I'm able to set the video to < (200,200) without any problems if I've enabled trial mode. I want to better understand this behavior since it seems more like a bug than anything else (based on their documentation).

Comment: Still seems like I'd have to ask all my users to enable that trial or they would see errors. It doesn't feel like a workable solution to me. Perhaps the situation will improve if YouTube integrate the features of that trial.

Comment: just to follow up, you're right about it not being a feasible solution. was just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's appears there is a restriction on some video which don't allow embeding video on size inferior to 200*200 (px). This restriction is not applied for all video (maybe older than last update youtube API, i don't know).

After some tests, this restriction is applied when youtube player readystate changed to status: `PlayerState.PLAYING (evt.data === 1)`

So as a basic workaround, you could change size of iframe 'on the fly' after the satus has been updated, see demo&code below:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eDZrP/6/)

```
var player,
     myWidth = "114px",
     myHeight = "65px";

 function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
     player = new YT.Player('testVideo', {
         height: myWidth,
         width: myHeight,
         videoId: '-rMTExNTx2s',
         events: {
             'onReady': onPlayerReady,
             'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
         },
          playerVars: {
             controls:0,
             showinfo:0
          }        
     });
 }

function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
     if (evt.data == -1) {
        evt.target.a.width = "200px"; 
        evt.target.a.height = "200px"; 
     }
     else if (evt.data == 1) {
          evt.target.a.className = "";
         evt.target.a.width = myWidth; 
         evt.target.a.height = myHeight; 
         done = true;
     }
 }
```

As you can ssee in this DEMO, i set an hidden class with css `.hidden{opacity:0}`. This is used to hide player before the video is loaded. Using `display:none;` doesn't work, its surely an other API restriction.
Still in this DEMO, you have to wait until the video has started to play to see the player appears.
You have now to find the best workaround which could fit your needs, using e.g a thumbnail image and moving from negative offset player to wished location when readystate has changed, hope you got the idea.

Comment: that fiddle works...it does what you want.                          so what is the problem now ?

Comment: It works for the particular video used in the example. It doesn't work for all videos (more importantly, it doesn't work for the specific set of videos I need it to work for). If I change the video ID, it breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/eDZrP/1/ I will accept if you can get it to work with the video Id from my fiddle or explain why it works for one video and not the other.

Comment: @roasted Very nice. Thank you.

Comment: @A.Wolff how to make it not autoplay?

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution, but have you thought about actually scaling down a larger player with the [CSS3 transform: scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform) property? Beware it's [not supported in IE < 9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

The main reason **not** to do this, though, is that you'll be reducing the size of the UI controls which in turn reduces usability.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try this out now. Size of the UI controls isn't a large issue since I'm implementing my own controls anyway.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. YouTube detects that the player is "too small" and refuses to play the video.